# "no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1". How to fix the client not the server

Tags: centos, ssh-keygen

So we recently updated our server and found an old linux client was failing to login and generating a *"no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1"*, on our new server.
Checking online I just see instructions to enable the use of "diffie-hellman-group1-sha1" which i don't want to do.
So the solution is simple... run ssh-keygen on the client and specify some some other key exchange method (eg "diffie-hellman-xxx-sha256"). However I don't seem to find such an option.
I hate to demonstrate my ignorance, but where am I going wrong?
is sha1 a default method and if so how do I change it?

Comment: The key exchange methods are more-or-less baked into the binaries and don't have much to do with the keypair. Your options are to update the ssh on the client or to enable the old kex method on the server. (Theoretically, the client could have better methods compiled in but disabled: `ssh -Q kex` will list them, but that would be highly unusual.)

Comment: thanks ... that makes sense.